# Why is my JLabel not shown?

Tags: java, swing, grid, jlabel, layout-manager

I am a new Java learner.

I am creating a GUI application.

This class gets a number from the user and shows a table on the Frame.

When I run my class, I enter a number and click the JButton, but the JLabel on my Frame is not shown.

It does not show me why not.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
//this Frame class use the association   
class Frame {
    JFrame f;
    JButton jb,jbclear;
    JTextField jt;
    JLabel jl1[]=new JLabel[10];
    EventHandler hand=new EventHandler();
    //constructor
    Frame(){
        f=new JFrame("Hello");
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLayout(null);

        JLabel jl=new JLabel("Enter the number");
        jl.setBounds(30,10,100,20);
        f.getContentPane().add(jl);

        jt=new JTextField();
        jt.setBounds(170,10,50,20);
        f.add(jt);

        jb=new JButton("Click");
        jb.setBounds(270,50,80,30);
        f.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(hand);

        jbclear=new JButton("Clear");
        jbclear.setBounds(270,90,80,30);
        f.add(jbclear);
        jbclear.addActionListener(hand);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }
    class EventHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource()==jb){
                 int num=Integer.parseInt((jt.getText()));
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                        int n=(num*i);
                        String s=String.valueOf(num)+" X "+i+" = "+n;
                       jl1[i]=new JLabel(s);
                    }
                    for(int i=0,k=80;i<10;i++){
                     jl1[i].setBounds(30,k,150,10);
                     f.add(jl1[i]);
                     jl1[i].setVisible(true);
                     k=k+30;
                    }

            }
            if(e.getSource()==jbclear){
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                   jl1[i].setText("");
                }
            }

        }
    }






    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Frame();

    }

}
```

Can we add  a component after creating and displaying a JFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You create labels `jl1[i]=new JLabel(s)` but they are not added to container.

Don't use null layout/setBounds() but choose a suitable one (e.g `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout`)

Comment: `but they are not added to container.` : they are added to frame yes hence they are added to a container.

Comment: @Sage you are right that they are added to frame but adding directly to frame works since java 6. Previous versions need container so it's better to define container and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is next:

1) add all your components in same maner, like that `f.getContentPane().add()`, bacause you add your compenents with `f.getContentPane().add()` and `f.add()` it's different containers.

2) if you add component to visible Frame/Panel/Container, you must to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods on container after adding, because of, without those methods, added component will be invisible. I change your `ActionListener` in next way(it do what you want) :

```
 class EventHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==jb){
             int num=Integer.parseInt((jt.getText()));
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    int n=(num*i);
                    String s=String.valueOf(num)+" X "+i+" = "+n;
                   jl1[i]=new JLabel(s);
                }
                for(int i=0,k=80;i<10;i++){
                 jl1[i].setBounds(30,k,150,10);
                 f.getContentPane().add(jl1[i]);

                 k=k+30;
                }
                f.getContentPane().revalidate();
                f.getContentPane().repaint();

        }
        if(e.getSource()==jbclear){
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
             f.getContentPane().remove(jl1[i]);
            }
            f.getContentPane().revalidate();
            f.getContentPane().repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

[JFrame revalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29)

I recommend you try to use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) instead of `setBounds()` method with null layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
             for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                 int n=(num*i);
                 String s=String.valueOf(num)+" X "+i+" = "+n;
                 jl1[i]=new JLabel(s);
             }
             for(int i=0,k=80;i<10;i++){
                jl1[i].setBounds(30,k,150,10);
                f.add(jl1[i]);
                jl1[i].setVisible(true);
```

Ok, you are adding `JLabel` to the `JFrame`, more accurately to the Frame's content pane, but you haven't called `repaint()` on `JFrame` to update the GUI. Just call, `f.repiant()` as soon as you have finished added the `labels` too have some output for temporary satisfaction.

> Can we add a component after creating and displaying a JFrame?

Yes, but we should use proper layout manager, After adding a component we should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to render the GUI appropriately.

Now some more things:

1. Do not work with `Null` layout(or Absolute Layout),
2. All the component's visible flag is `true` by default, you don't need to call `setVisible(true)` on such component except with the application window e.g., `JFrame`
3. Swing uses EDT to it's GUI rendering task. Hence we should make all the necessary update to the GUI, including showing our application first time upon starting, should also be put inside the EDT. `SwingUtilies.invokeLater(new Runnabe(){})` do just that.

**Tutorial:**

1. [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
2. [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: No need to revalidate() when setBounds() were called. Revalidate asks LayoutManager to set the bounds. No need to call this particular code in SwingUtilies.invokeLater(). It's enough to call it directly from actionPerformed()

Comment: Don't know how your comment is relevant to my answer! probably i am missing something. When we are using layout manager, we should call `revalidate()` upon adding a new component or removing a component, Which i specifically said. And We need to update GUI inside EDT. `ActionPerfomed` function invoked by `AnctionEvent` already runs inside the EDT. But showing window + updating GUI from other thread should do be done in EDT using SwingUtilities. The OP is currently showing main window(JFrame) from main thread